# Clonezilla won't boot up

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, clonezilla

I'm new to Ubuntu, and trying to make a backup with Clonezilla, but I can get only to the Clonezilla menu and after that I get a blank screen. I tried different USBs, but with no result. I also tried different Clonezilla versions. I have Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 installed.
What can cause that problem?